# Hidden Service : To hide from isp or not to?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, whonix

My goal is to host a hidden service using Tor and Whonix.

My computer is running debian with Whonix on virtual box.

The question is, what is the best practices? Should I allow whonix to hide my Tor usage from the ISP or continue using Tor as when I was not running a hidden service? (Thus, ISP was able to observe that I am connected to Tor network).

Comment: Your question is confusing: It is not clear what whonix has to do with your question. It is not clear how this is a question about hosting. As for 'should I hide my tor use' (on whonix?), you don't provide any information to base an answer on. You should try and rephrase the question, so that it is clear what you want to know, want to achieve, want to avoid.

Comment: Sorry, here ill try and rephrase it.

Answer (score 1):

In running a hidden service, the major deanonymization risk is poor OPSEC. There's also the attack described in [Biryukov et al. (2013)](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/cache/oakland2013-trawling.pdf). But there, getting your identity from your ISP is the last step.

Still, you may not want to advertise using Tor. I don't.

Answer (score 0):

The EFF ([Electronic Frontier Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Frontier_Foundation)) has [an FAQ page](https://www.eff.org/torchallenge/faq.html) which details its legal reccommendations about running Tor. It doesn't specifically mention hidden services, but its advice concerning exit nodes - i.e. be as transparent as possible - is probably similarly relevant.

Their recommendations assume that your ISP is Tor-friendly (or at least Tor-tolerant); if you know yours isn't, then perhaps check [the list on the Tor wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/GoodBadISPs) for one that is.

Their advice on subpoenas and DMCA notices might also be of use, though hopefully never needed.